# MongoDB and PHP simple login

Tags: php, mongodb

I am new to mongoDb and PHP. 
I am trying to create a simple login page which will take the user input from the text fields and look in the database if the record exists.

For now I am able to pass hard coded values which redirects me to a new page but I am unable to query the database.

If someone can guide me in the rite direction. I have looked at various tutorials online but have not been able to get what I need.

```
<? PHP      
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
<title> Movie Database </title>
</head>

<?PHP

$_SESSION["loggedInUser"] = $username;


    try {
        // open connection to MongoDB server
        $conn = new Mongo('localhost');

        // access database
        $db = $conn->test;

        // access collection
        $collection = $db->items;


        $userName = $_POST['username'];
        $userPass = $_POST['userPassword'];


        $user = $db->$collection->findOne(array('username'=> 'user1', 'password'=> 'pass1'));

        foreach ($user as $obj) {
            echo 'Username' . $obj['username'];
            echo 'password: ' . $obj['password'];
            if($userName == 'user1' && $userPass == 'pass1'){
                echo 'found'            
            }
            else{
                echo 'not found'            
            }

        }

        // disconnect from server
        $conn->close();

    } catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
        die('Error connecting to MongoDB server');
    } catch (MongoException $e) {
        die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

$_SESSION["loggedInUser"] = $correct;

?>

<body>
<br>
<center><h1> Welcome to CS348 Login Page </h1></center>
<br>
<form action="page2.php" METHOD="POST">
<label>Username :</label>
<input type="text" Name="username">
<br>
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" Name="userPassword">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
<br>
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure how to take the userinput from the text boxes and query the database.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Please _please_ **please** don't store passwords as plain text. [Hash and salt](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). There are plenty of authentication libraries out there, you really don't need to write your own.

Comment: @ChristianVarga I will surely change that (will look that up and see how that gets implemented) but for now just want to learn how to query database. Thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the username and password from user input you need to do something like below;

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['userPassword'];
```

Then you can use:

```
$user = $db->$collection->findOne(array('username'=> $username, 'password'=> $password));
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I did make the changes you suggested and they make more sense. But my webpage is coming out to be blank. Is there a way I can debug that? I have modified the code if you could have a look. Thank you for the help

Comment: you are redirecting your form to page2.php, is this the same page where you have this PHP code?

Comment: I was using page2 to redirect my output to see what values I get. I did figure out the error of not displaying anything ( I was missing semi colons). Should I redirect to the same page?

Comment: Yes, your php code to get the username and password is on same page, or you can move your PHP code to page2.php

Comment: thank you for that but I just have one last lingering question. The php code to move to next page will be all the if else statements rite?

Comment: No, everything starting from $_SESSION["loggedInUser"] = $username;